# PCB Power Divider Tee for RS 485

Tags: rs485, power-divider

For a RS-485 Communication using a [Maxim MAX3292](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3291-MAX3292.pdf) Driver, Full Duplex, 1/4 load unit (54 \$\Omega\$), 5 Mbps, with UTP 120 \$\Omega\$, standard cable, for each receiving unit I am thinking on a design placing two (equal) connectors, and making a tee directly in the PCB, connecting both to the Driver.

Being 10 Mbps the maximum realizable speed with this device, 
Should I consider a strip geometry as Power Divider, for matching impedances (\$\lambda\sim2m\$ for 70% VF) ? or a lumped parameters Power Divider like [this](https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/wilkinson_power_split_2.php) (with 180pF, 90pF and 2.7uH)? Or an specific device|driver? Should I take some design cautions on this tee (angle, dimensions, lengths, details), or it is enough to simply draw a "T" and minimizing the vias quantity (see the referencial PCB sketch)?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is the speed the RS485 link needs to run at? Are you going to run it at the full 10Mbps?

Comment: At 500kbps, testing distances starting from 100ft.